# Default 64 bit address data type on Windows

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit, memory-address

I need to manipulate 64 bit addresses on Windows 7 64 bit, I'm currently using something like

```
BYTE m_myAddress[8];
```

but if I need to add `0x60` to the address, it becomes quite tricky. I could convert it, but I wanted to ask what data type is best suited for this.

What data type should be used to store 64 bit addresses?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would have thought that `void*` or `char*` is the most natural. `char*` especially if you want to do arithmetic on addresses.

```
char* addr = ...;
...
addr += 0x60;
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of it in the first place. Great!

Comment: If you need to do more complex operations (such as bit twiddling), I'd recommend using `uintptr_t` (from `<stdint.h>`), which is an integral type guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer-sized value.